# create pandas column with conditionals

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

The value of column A can be -1, 0 and 1. How to create a new column with conditions: column A; value different from 0 in the line below (-1,1), add the value of column X, if value of column X equals 0 then add the next value different from 0. In the other lines of this new column, assign the value 0.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'a': [-1,-1,-1,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1], 
     'x': [0.00,-2.13,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.21,-0.63,0.00,0.29,-0.11,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.62,0.00,
           -0.36,0.00,-0.03,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.22,0.05,0.00]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

**desired result**

```
    a   x   r
0   -1  0.00    0.00
1   -1  -2.13   0.00
2   -1  0.00    0.00
3   0   0.00    0.00
4   0   0.00    0.00
5   -1  0.00    0.00
6   -1  0.00    0.00
7   -1  0.21    0.21
8   -1  -0.63   0.00
9   -1  0.00    0.00
10  -1  0.29    0.00
11  -1  -0.11   0.00
12  -1  0.00    0.00
13  0   0.00    0.00
14  0   0.00    0.00
15  0   0.00    0.00
16  0   0.00    0.00
17  0   0.00    0.00
18  1   0.00    0.00
19  1   0.62    0.62
20  1   0.00    0.00
21  0   -0.36   0.00
22  0   0.00    0.00
23  0   -0.03   0.00
24  0   0.00    0.00
25  1   0.00    0.00
26  1   0.00    0.00
27  1   0.22    0.22
28  1   0.05    0.00
29  1   0.00    0.00
```

Comment: You got the code. Please make a reproducible example.

Comment: Also, in addition to a complete [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") containing both data, and code that can be copied and pasted  please clarify what you mean by " column A; value different from 0 in the line below (-1,1), add the value of column X, if value of column X equals 0 then add the next value different from 0"

Comment: in a new column 'r', whenever the value in column 'a' is different from 0 in a row below, the value of column 'r' equals column 'x', if value of column 'x' is equal to zero sum the next nonzero value. other values ​​of column 'r' equal to zero.